# Proof for de Moivre's Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, math-history

I have a book that has a brief history of the complex numbers and it covers de Moivre's formula:

$(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^n = \cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)$.

I am very curious as to how this result was originally found, or derived, BEFORE Euler's formula was around. Also, what was the original proof of this?

Comment: Probably by induction.

Comment: Induction indeed...and basic trigonometric formulas, of course.

Comment: @Christopher have answer working on putting it together.

Comment: I was puzzled by this result when I saw it because the way I was introduced to multiplication of complex numbers was that one multiplies the absolute values and adds the angles, so this formula seemed like a complete triviality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Euler was the first to write down de Moirve's formula which I found in [The Elementary Mathematical Works of Leonhard Euler](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/eulernotes99.pdf) starting on page 29. Euler found
$$
(\cos(x)\pm i\sin(x))(\cos(y)\pm i\sin(y))(\cos(z)\pm i\sin(z)) = \cos(x \pm y \pm z)\pm i\sin(x\pm y\pm z)
$$ 
from here he deduce what we call de Moirve's theorem
$$
(\cos(x)\pm i\sin(x))^n = \cos(nx)\pm i\sin(nx)
$$
Then it follows that
\begin{align}
\cos(nx) &= 1/2[(\cos(x)+ i\sin(x))^n+(\cos(x) - i\sin(x))^n]\tag{1}\\
\sin(nx) &= 1/2[(\cos(x)+ i\sin(x))^n-(\cos(x) - i\sin(x))^n]\tag{2}
\end{align}
Euler than expanded equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ by the binomial theorem. He then let $x$ be a small angle approximation and $n$ be infinitely large so that $xn$ was finite. Let $xn=v$. Then $\sin(x) = x = v/n$ and we get 
\begin{align}
\cos(v) &= 1 - \frac{v^2}{2!} + \cdots\\
\sin(v) &= v - \frac{v^3}{3!} + \cdots
\end{align}
Using equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ and letting $j = n$ be the infinitely large number so that $jx=v$ so that $nx = v = v/j$. Now we have $\sin(x) = v/j$ and $\cos(x)=1$. With these substitutions, we get
\begin{align}
\cos(v) &=\frac{(1+iv/j)^j+(1-iv/j)^j}{2}\\
\sin(v) &=\frac{(1+iv/j)^j-(1-iv/j)^j}{2i}
\end{align}
In the linked document, the author who compiled the document (Euler) previously has shown that $(1+z/j)^j = e^z$. Letting $z=\pm iv$, we get
\begin{align}
e^{iv} &= \cos(v) + i\sin(v)\\
e^{-iv} &= \cos(v) - i\sin(v)
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer and great link! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Christopher you probably want to go through the link since I left out the some details as well as the binomial expansion of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @dustin Very nice approach!

Comment: @Mehdi unfortunately, Euler gets all the credit here. I have no idea why this was named after de Moirve though. It mentions he was working on some equations but I don't see the relation or why he gets the credit.

Comment: @dustin well he has been great (and is). By the way I just found an interesting youtube video on Euler: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-DV26x6n_Q

Comment: @dustin by the way, I will check a bit on the naming history ... soon. I will come back to this post again.